# Converting in node js base 64

Tags: node.js

I have a var called data, which is essentially a string. I want to encode it to base 64, and I did:

```
data = new Buffer(data).toString('base64');
```

But all it becomes is AAAA. How do I fix this?

Comment: what was the content of `data` before the conversion?

Comment: A very large string. I made it to data = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data).toString('base64'));, but it still isn't recognized.

Comment: Is that directly copied? Because you have an error with your parentheses. Should be `data = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data)).toString('base64')`

Comment: I tried this and it's working: new Buffer('Man is distinguished').toString('base64') --> 'TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQ=' as in the base64 wiki article